# Change text encoding use js solution?

Tags: javascript, encoding

Since Native File APIs are supported for web developers.

Like this example https://web.dev/browser-nativefs/,

Text encoding may come to be a question, so I want to know is there any solution for change string encoding in JS/ES that likes the Java code below

```
 byte[] b = s.getBytes("UTF-8");
 String n = new String(b,"UTF-8");
```

Or is there any standard on W3C to solve it?

If have, can it decode string with certain charactor set(like BIG5), and then change it to UTF-8?

Answer (score -1):

Please check out the documentation of [`TextDecoder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder) and [`TextEncoder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder) respectively. These APIs serve for converting from one encoding to the other.

Here is an example:

```js
const text = ''; // Some Windows-1252 encoded text
var uint8array = new TextEncoder('windows-1252').encode(text);
```

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Improved the reply.